# Understanding Excel lambda

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, office365, excel-lambda

I am trying to understand better how does the recursivity works in Excel using the Lambda function. I didn't manage to wrap my head around how to increment the "value" the function is at.

The idea here is to stack all the unique "Invoices" value within one cell with a "-" as a delimiter as highlighted in blue in the screenshot.

[image]

```
l_uf = LAMBDA(array,criteria,
    UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(array,2),CHOOSECOLS(array,1)=criteria,"")));
```

---

```
l_ar = lambda(array, criteria,
        let(v, l_uf(array, criteria),
            n, counta(v),
            if(n="","",
            CHOOSEROWS(v, n) & "-" &CHOOSEROWS(v, n-1))));
```

and then I tried the lambda function l_ar which only retries the 2 last rows without going through the all array... please help

Thank you very much

Comment: I think too much unwanted verbose functions. And it would not return the as expected.

Comment: That formula which given to you will never return the data as concatenated for the invoices. based on suplier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=VSTACK({"Suplier","Invoices"},
DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(B3:B12),
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,
TEXTJOIN("-",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C12,B3:B12=y))))))),1))
```

---

In a more basic and understandable way could be

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E11`

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(B:B,1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `F11`

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,E11=B:B)))
```

The above formula obviously needs to be filled down.

---

If you are eager to use LAMBDA() and want to spill the whole array, then you could use it in this way as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J2`

```
=LET(_uniqueSup,UNIQUE(TOCOL(B:B,1)),
HSTACK(_uniqueSup,BYROW(_uniqueSup,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("-",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,x=B:B)))))))
```

---

Using `LET()` and defining each steps as variables:

[image]

---

```
=LET(_data,B2:C12,
_headers,TAKE(_data,1),
_suplier,DROP(_data,1,-1),
_usuplier,UNIQUE(_suplier),
_invoice,DROP(_data,1,1),
_invoicedelimited,BYROW(_usuplier,LAMBDA(u,TEXTJOIN("-",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(_invoice,_suplier=u))))),
_joindata,HSTACK(_usuplier,_invoicedelimited),
VSTACK(_headers,_joindata))
```

---

To use the above within a `LAMBDA()` which you can use in defined name manager with a friendly name:

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(_data,array,
_headers,TAKE(_data,1),
_suplier,DROP(_data,1,-1),
_usuplier,UNIQUE(_suplier),
_invoice,DROP(_data,1,1),
_invoicedelimited,BYROW(_usuplier,LAMBDA(u,TEXTJOIN("-",1,
UNIQUE(FILTER(_invoice,_suplier=u))))),
_joindata,HSTACK(_usuplier,_invoicedelimited),
VSTACK(_headers,_joindata)))(B2:C12)
```

---

Comment: Re "*to make the above recursive just wrap within a `LAMBDA`*", are you sure that makes it *recursive*? A *recursive* `LAMBDA` is one which is self-referential and which iterates/loops. Wrapping a formula within a `LAMBDA` does not by definition make it recursive.

Answer (score 3):

### Creating a Lambda Function

**The Formula**

```
=LET(Data,A1:B10,Delimiter,"-",
    d,DROP(Data,1),di,TAKE(d,,-1),
    du,TAKE(d,,1),u,UNIQUE(du),
    ui,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,FILTER(di,du=r,"")))),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),HSTACK(u,ui)))
```

**The LAMBDA Formula**

- You usually don't use this format.

```
=LAMBDA(Data,Delimiter,LET(
    d,DROP(Data,1),di,TAKE(d,,-1),
    du,TAKE(d,,1),u,UNIQUE(du),
    ui,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,FILTER(di,du=r,"")))),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),HSTACK(u,ui))))(A1:B10,"-")
```

**The LAMBDA Function**

- This one you will put in the name manager and call it e.g. `JoinInv` and use it with

  ```
  =JoinInv(A1:B10,"-")
  ```

```
=LAMBDA(Data,Delimiter,LET(
    d,DROP(Data,1),di,TAKE(d,,-1),
    du,TAKE(d,,1),u,UNIQUE(du),
    ui,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,FILTER(di,du=r,"")))),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),HSTACK(u,ui))))
```

[image]

**The Variables**

- d - `A2:B10` - data without headers
- di - `B2:B10` - the invoice data
- du - `A2:B10` - the supplier data
- u - `D3:D4` - a single-column array of the unique suppliers
- ui - `E3:E4` - the invoices joined into cells (rows) of a column
- `TAKE(Data,1)` - `A1:B1` - the headers

**The flow**

- `DROP` and `TAKE` are used to reference the various parts of the range.
- `UNIQUE` is used to get unique suppliers.
- In the `BYROW` Lambda helper function, the invoice data is filtered by the suppliers' data column values being equal to the unique value in the current row and it is `TEXTJOIN`-ed to get a single string (per row). In the end, we get the joined invoices in as many rows as there are unique suppliers.
- `HSTACK` is used to stack the joined invoices to the unique suppliers, while `VSTACK` is used to stack this resulting column duo to the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my output..

```
=LET(data,A3:A11,result,B3:B11,unq,UNIQUE(data),VSTACK(A2:B2,HSTACK(unq,MAP(unq,LAMBDA(val,TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(val=data,result,"")))))))
```

[image: result]